# QGIS Raster calculator calculates „-inf, inf“ instead of no-data

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, nodata

I am trying to extract Vegetation from an aerial image.

First I calculated a DEM for vegetation height and a binary image (0,1) for cover.
Then I divided DEM by binary. Result was a raster with vegetation height data and “no-data”, which is what I want. This worked very well, until recently.

Suddenly I get “inf” instead of no data. I even tried to reproduce previous results and this is now happening there as well. I honestly have no idea what has changed. To reproduce the previous calculations I used raster images that definitely have worked before, but now they do not.

Has anyone any idea how I can get back my “no data” again?
Alternatively how to deal with inf?

Comment: the result of dividing by 0 is often represented by `inf` or `nan` but it can be just about anything. Maybe you could multiply by the binary instead

Answer (score 1):

**Approach**

You may want to convert this inf value to Nan or NoData. you can easily do it by running raster operation like Self equals. `x==x`

1. For all real values, this will be `True`.
2. For all Nans, NoData, or `Inf`, `-Inf`. This will be `False`.

So you will get a binary raster.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was so troubled that I am actually reinstalling qgis right now, so I can't try it.
 
You write I'll get a binary raster, does this mean that I consequently lose the vegetation height data? But I need to keep these values.

Comment: @ManishSahu: Self equals does not work in QGIS raster calculator : `"raster@1" == "raster@1"` shows `Expression invalid`. Using `"raster@1" = "raster@1"`, fol `nodata` the result remains `nodata`

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know why the raster calculator did not work, why saga calculator did not work. But using the grass r.mapcalc.simple did work.

I literally did not change anything but the calculator and got my result.